# i can't navigate from one window to other

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

I want to navigate from Login.js to home.js so anyone who help me for this.

```
//app.js

var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var tabbar = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({
    title:"Login"
    });

var mainwin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url:"Login/login.js"
    });
var signupwin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url:"Login/Home.js"
    });

var tabLogin = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title:"Login",
    window:mainwin
    });

var tabsignup = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title:"SignUp",
    window:signupwin
    });

var nav = Titanium.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
    window:mainwin
    });


tabbar.addTab(tabLogin);
tabbar.addTab(tabsignup);    
tabbar.open({
    transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP
  });
//-------------------------------------------------------
//Login.js

//Ti.include('Homescreen/HomeScreen.js');

var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
win.title="Login";

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
        title:'first window',
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    });

var lbluser = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:"UserName",
        width: 60,
        height: 32,
        left: 10,
        font:{fontcolor:"blue",fontsize:12},
        top: 10
    });

win.add(lbluser);

var username = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    top:10,
    left:50,
    width:250,
    height:40,
    hintText:'Username',
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
win.add(username);

var lblpass = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:"Password",
        width: 60,
        height: 32,
        left: 10,
        top: 50,
        font:{fontcolor:"white",fontsize:12}
    });

win.add(lblpass);
var password = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    top:60,
    left:50,
    width:250,
    height:40,
    hintText:'Password',
    passwordMask:true,
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
win.add(password);

var loginBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Login',
    top:110,
    width:90,
    height:35,
    borderRadius:1,
    font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14}
});
win.add(loginBtn);


/*
 Login Button Click Event
*/



loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    if (username.value == 'Bimal' && password.value == 'Pass')
    { 
      alert("ok");
       var home = Ti.UI.createWindow({
          title:"Home Screen",
          url:'Home.js',
          _parent:win,
          nav:win.nav,
          rootWindow:win.rootWindow
        });
        win.open(home);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Username/Password are required");
    }
});


win.open();

//-----------------------------------------------
//Home.js

var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

win.title = "Home Screen";
var username = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    top:10,
    left:50,
    width:300,
    height:40,
    hintText:'Username',
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
win.add(username);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just call setActiveTab using the correct index.

For example if you place the below button code into login.js it should set the focus to the home tab when the button is pressed.

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
var tabGroup = win.tabGroup;
var b1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Press Me',
    left : 10, top : 100, right : 10, height : 40
});

b1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   tabGroup.setActiveTab(1);
});

win.add(b1);
```

More examples of this are available here https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/tab_groups.js